# gorm append updates all existing records too

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using Mysql as a db.
I've a goORM model as defined below.

```
type A struct {
    *repository.BaseEntity
    AId     string    `gorm:"column:a_id;type:varchar(50) NOT NULL"`
    B       []B       `gorm:"foreignkey:AId;association_foreignkey:AId;auto_preload"`
}
```

This obviously is an overly simplified version of a complex model.
Now I've an instance of A which currently has 3 Bs.

```
aInstance = ...
db.Model(aInstance).Association("B").Append(B{dummyField : 'dummyValue'})
```

I am expecting this to just create a new record in B table. But actually it also updates those previous 3 Bs.
Is this expected behaviour ? Coz those 3 queries are certainly not required.
Is there any way to avoid those ?